# Using middleware config from extension methods in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-middleware

I've developed a piece of ASP.NET Core middleware. I've simplified the middleware in this post, to make the problem clearer.

The middleware is configured in `Startup.cs` like this:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    ...
    app.UseMyMiddleware(42);
    ...
}
```

The integer (`42`) is stored in the middleware instance and everything is fine.

Now I want to create some helper methods as extension methods:

```cs
public static int Add(this int i)
{
    return i + TODO;
}
```

I would like the method to add the value of `i` to the value (`42`) sent to the middleware.

Currently I've saved the value of `42` in a public static var inside the middleware and access this from my extension method:

```cs
public static int Add(this int i)
{
    return i + MyMiddleware.Value;
}
```

I don't like this solution for various reasons. Any ideas to how this can be solved in a better way would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You could add your middleware class instance to the IoC container and use injection to get a reference to it when you need it.

Comment: You won’t have much success with such an extension method. You cannot resolve any non-static stuff with it, and ASP.NET Core *by design* avoids statics. The proper way would be to create some kind of helper that you need to resolve via dependency injection. – That being said, what kind of value is this actually? Is this a value that is request specific (then static is the wrong approach anyway) or is this really just constructed *once*? Is it a constant that is fixed in your code, or does this come from configuration?

Comment: @poke The value is indeed static per application and only created once. Being able to specify the value in config and injecting that in various places (as proposed in the other commend and in an answer) would improve the code for sure. But it doesn't make the value available from an extension method.

Comment: @poke If you want to look at some real code, here's a PR I made, implementing the static variable (that I don't like): https://github.com/elmahio/Elmah.Io.AspNetCore/pull/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, this won’t work with extension methods. Extension methods are static and as such can only access other static members. ASP.NET Core however is *by design* not using any statics and extensively uses [dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection) to manage the lifetime of objects and to access dependencies.

So usually, the proper way would be to move your extension method into some kind of non-static helper object which you can then inject where you need to access it. Of course, this will not allow you to easily call it wherever you need it but requires you to *explicitly* depend on it (which is one of the points of dependency injection).

That being said, your explicit case is a bit different. As I could see from your [linked pull request](https://github.com/elmahio/Elmah.Io.AspNetCore/pull/2), your extension method looks like this (note, I combined two methods here to make it clear):

```
public static async Task ShipAsync(this Exception exception, HttpContext context)
{
    await MessageShipper.ShipAsync(
        ElmahIoMiddleware.ApiKey.AssertApiKeyInMiddleware(),
        ElmahIoMiddleware.LogId.AssertLogIdInMiddleware(),
        exception.Message, context, new ElmahIoSettings(), exception);
}
```

Why does that matter? Because you are passing `HttpContext`. And the HTTP context gives us access to dependency injection. So we can actually resolve things from the dependency injection container:

```
public static async Task ShipAsync(this Exception exception, HttpContext context)
{
    var elmahIoConfig = context.RequestServices.GetService<ElmahIoConfiguration>();

    await MessageShipper.ShipAsync(
        elmahIoConfig.ApiKey,
        elmahIoConfig.LogId,
        exception.Message, context, new ElmahIoSettings(), exception);
}
```

Now, you just need to make sure that `ElmahIoConfiguration` gets filled properly when you register the middleware. Note that I am not requesting the middleware instance here because middlewares are usually not registered with dependency injection. It makes more sense to introduce a separate object which you can then inject into the middleware and initialize there.

In your case, you should really move the middleware configuration into your application settings and use the `IOptions<>` pattern to configure it at `ConfigureServices` level. Configuring middleware as you add it to the pipeline in `Configure` is not really a common pattern in ASP.NET Core 2 anymore.

Comment: Wow. Didn't knew about the `RequestServices` property on `HttpContext`. Only thing missing now is, that my `Use` method needs to register the `ElmahIoConfiguration` object. Do you know if that is possible? I cannot seem to find a reference to the services collection through the app builder.

Comment: When thinking about it, it is probably prettier to add a new `AddElmahIo`-method (that takes all the configuration). Then require the client to call it from the `ConfigureServices`-method. The `AddElmahIo`-method would add a singleton object to the services collection. The `UseElmahIo`-method would then pull the config object through `app.ApplicationServices.GetService` and the extension method would pull the config through the HttpContext (`RequestServices.GetService`). What do you think?

Comment: Yes, you would make a `services.AddElmahIo` in `Configure` where you set up and configure your components, and then you would only use the middleware in `Configure` which would then inject the necessary dependencies and configuration itself. – No need for the `UseElmahIo` to pull anything from DI, the middleware object itself should do that. The `UseElmahIo` should be equivalent to `app.UseMiddleware<ElmahIoMiddleware>()`.

Comment: (Btw. if you end up creating a new pull request for this, feel free to ping me on it, and I’ll look over it :) )

Comment: Wouldn't you pull the config in the following method: `public static IApplicationBuilder UseElmahIo(this IApplicationBuilder app)`. Or would you delay this to the middleware class itself? The `Invoke`-method takes a `HttpContext` as a parameter, so resolving the config could be as late as in the `Invoke`-method.

Comment: I'm modifying the PR right now. Will ping you when it's there :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the appsettings.json to store this information and then use the built-in DI to inject it into your middleware?

**appsettings.json**

```
{
    "MiddlewareConfiguration":
    {
        "MiddlewareValue":42,
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<MiddlewareConfiguration>(configuration.GetSection("MiddlewareConfiguration"));
}
```

**MiddlewareConfiguration.cs**

```
public class MiddlewareConfiguration
{
    public int MiddlewareValue { get; set; }
}
```

You can then inject it into your middleware, e.g.:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, IOptions<MiddlewareConfiguration> config)
```

Comment: Moving the value to `appsettings.json` and add to DI doesn't make it available from an extension method. I agree, it would be a good solution to specify settings like this, but what I need is to be able to access them from a static method basically.

Comment: Sorry I must have misunderstood the question, why do you need to access it via a static method?

Comment: Usually I don't need to access it from the static method. But in this case, I want to be able to trigger the logic inside the middleware manually. It's an exception logging piece of middleware. And in this case, I want to be able to log a exception manually, by creating a logging extension method on the Exception class: catch(Exception e) e.LogThis()